# How would I position my "+1" animation wherever my node comes in contact with a coin in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I have this code where when my hero node gets in contact with a coin a "+1" animation runs.  Right now its in the middle of the screen every time the hero node makes contact with the coins. I want the position of that animation to be wherever the hero node made contact with the coin. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
        let addCoinsLabel = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plusone")
        addCoinsLabel.setScale(0.8)
        addCoinsLabel.zPosition = 200
        addCoinsLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: self.frame.size.height*0.7)
        self.addChild(addCoinsLabel)

        let actionLabelfadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.3)
        let actionLabelFadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.3)
        let actionLabelMove = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 100), 
        duration: 0.3)
        let actionRemoveFromParent = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([actionLabelfadeIn, 
        actionLabelMove, actionLabelFadeOut, actionRemoveFromParent])

        addCoinsLabel.runAction(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addCoinsLabel.position = CGPoint(x: coin.position.x, y: coin.position.y)
```